# Java Regex making expression to match a) b) c) d)

Tags: java, regex

everybody! I'm trying to create a regular expression to match `"a), b), c) and d)"`as opposed to upper case format `"A), B), C), D)"` in a string `"a) option a b) option b c) option c d) option d"`. This is what I've come up with:

```
[a-d]\)
```

And it correctly matches my string (tested here: https://www.regexpal.com/)

But when I try to implement the same in Java, it does not match my string:

```
String myString = "a) option a b) option b c) option c d) option d";
String myRegEx = "[a-d]\\)";

System.out.println("Output: " + Pattern.matches(meRegEx, myString));
```

Produces:

```
 Output: false
```

Why?

Comment: are you trying to match strings like "a)c)d)"? Or are these separated by commas/spaces? Or only single "a)", "b)" etc?

Comment: I'm trying to determine whether options are in uppercase like : `"A) option a B) option b C) option c D) option d";` or in lower case like: '"a) option a b) option b c) option c d) option d";'. 
And I expect that if it is the latter (lower case), my java code will produce `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex instead :

```
String myRegEx = "([a-d]\\).*?)+";
```

details :

- `[a-d]\).*?` match any lower case letter followed by a parenthesis `)` followed by one or more character.
- all this inside a group `(..)+` which will be repeated one or more time.

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9mQqoU/1)

Answer (score 0):

The point you miss is the diferrence beetwen perl regex and java regex

on perl regex match is true when you match a part of the myString
on java you have to match the full myString with your regex

titi a) option a b) option b c) option c d) option d

`String myRegEx = ".*[a-b]\).*"`

in java you to match the full string like in perl you use in your regex ^ and $

`^.*[a-b]\).*$`

lio

Comment: Thank you @user1680848! That is exactly what I misunderstood!